# How to release a Python application that uses API keys to the public?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I would like to release the code for an application I made in Python to the public, just as a pastebin link. However, the app needs a client ID, secret and user agent to access the API (for reddit in this case).

How can I store the key strings in the python code without giving everyone free reign on my api access? Maybe a hashing function or similar?

Comment: Why not just put a note saying "Insert your own API key, etc. here"? Or put that information in a text file that you document but don't provide.

Comment: When I put up some code that uses API keys on Github, I usually read the the keys from a config file or something similar and then add that file to my .gitignore

Comment: You're probably violating terms of use for the API key by, essentially, allowing others to use it. The better approach for sharing would be to separate out the secrets (into a class or global), marking them with dummy values, and provide a link to information on how another user can get their own.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want to provide the actual keys and other private information at all, hashed or otherwise. Besides being a security issue, it probably violates all sorts of agreements you implicitly made with the provider.

Anyone using the application should be able to get their own key in the same manner you did. You can (and should) provide instructions for how to do this.

Your application should expect the key information in a well documented format, usually a configuration file, that the user must provide once they have obtained the keys in question. You should document the exact format you expect to read the key in as well.

Your documentation could also include a dummy file with empty or obvious placeholder values for the user to fill in. It may be overkill, but I would recommend making sure that any placeholders you use are guaranteed not to be valid keys. This will go a long way to avoiding any accidents with the agreements you could violate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. Should've been obvious

Comment: @EthanCrooks. It will be from now on. The first time never is somehow :)